# JQ: How do I extract item which has part of subitem value of "FOO"

Tags: jq

I have quite long input with the following structure:

```json
{
    "name": "test1",
    "selfLink": "https://1.2.3.4",
    "items": [
        {
           "name": "test1",
           "rules": [
                {
                   "expression": "expresFOOsion1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ....next similar item, 
    ....next similar item, 
    ....next similar item
}
```

this finds the correct item(s):

```sh
jq '.items[].rules[]|select(.expression|test(".*FOO.*"))' testfile.json
```

but i need to get the "name" : "test1" to the output.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: `.rules[]` should be inside the `select`. Also, need `any` to avoid duplicating results if multiple rules match. [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/NIQkKp9gb6)